# Clojure: doseq function to print range of numbers from the top down

Tags: clojure

I am writing an assignment in Clojure which should display a list of prime numbers between 2 inputs: `from` and `to`. I managed to do that with this function:

```
(defn print-top-primes [ from to ]
  (doseq
    [ i (prime-seq from to) ]   ;;prime-seq returns a range of numbers
    (println i)
  )
)
```

Which gives the output:

```
 (print-top-primes 50 100)   
53
59
61
67
71
73
79
83
89
97
=> nil
```

However, the assignment specifies that i need the numbers to be printed like this:

```
 (print-top-primes 50 100)
97
89
83
79
73
71
67
61
59
53
Total=732
=> nil
```

I cannot manage to use `doseq` to print the numbers from top to bottom.

I also need to add the total of all the primes but I am not sure how this would work as the `doseq` function does not hold each value of `i`.

Perhaps I am using the wrong function, however the example in the assignment outputs a:

```
=> nil
```

...suggesting that it is a `doseq` function?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: reverse (https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reverse)

Comment: wow that was easy haha, thank you that worked!

Comment: Still struggling with adding all the values to be outputted as a total

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way would be like:

```
(defn print-top-primes [from to]
  (let [top-primes (reverse (prime-seq from to))
        total (apply + top-primes)]
    (doseq [i top-primes]
      (println i))
    (printf "Total = %d\n" total)))

=> (print-top-primes 50 100)
97
89
83
79
73
71
67
61
59
53
Total = 732
nil
```

If you really want to avoid making three passes through the list of primes (one for `reverse`, one for `apply +`, and one for printing), you can try something like:

```
(defn print-top-primes [from to]
  (loop [primes (prime-seq from to)
         total 0]
    (let [p (last primes)]
      (if p
        (do (println p)
            (recur (butlast primes) (+ total p)))
        (printf "Total = %d\n" total)))))
```

But you would want to verify that it's enough of a performance gain to justify the increased complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you jas,

Looking at your answer helped me come up with an even easier way i think, this is the way i have been taught so i should probably implement it like this:

```
(defn print-top-primes [ from to ]
  (doseq [i (reverse (prime-seq from to))]
    (println i))
  (printf "Total = %d\n" (reduce + (prime-seq from to)))
)
```

Giving the correct output!

I am wondering now is there a way to just output the first 10 largest primes, given there was a large number of primes?

Comment: This is fine, but often you want to avoid calling a function like `prime-seq` twice with the same parameters, since presumably takes some amount of work to calculate the result. Using `let` allows you to make the call once and use the result in multiple places.

Comment: To get just the first 10 primes:  `(take 10 (reverse (prime-seq from to)))`

Comment: Ahh ok yeah that makes sense. Thank you for the help mate!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your course is going to mention it next, but in any case I would not use `doseq` here but `loop` and `recur`:

```
(loop [elements (reverse (range 10))
       sum 0]
  (if (empty? elements)
    sum
    (let [[head & tail] elements]
      (println head)
      (recur tail (+ sum head)))))
```

Prints:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Returns:

```
45
```

Instead of returning the value, you can easily write the required `Total` line and return nil.

The `loop` macro allows to define accumulators (like `sum`). I use the `[head & tail]` notation to destructure the sequence of elements in two parts. The reversed sequence is traversed only once.

> [returns nil] ...suggesting that it is a doseq function?

First, `doseq` is a macro, and second, there are so many ways to return `nil` that you cannot guess if the example you have is using `doseq` or not. Whether you have to use `doseq` or not should be told by the assignment, maybe you are under no obligation to use it.